# Creating new instance of an object

Tags: javascript, object, instance

I began writing code assuming that:

```
person1 = person
```

will give me a new instance, it doesn't. `person1` is actually a reference/pointer to `person`.

```
person = {age : 2}

person1 = person;

person.age = 3;

alert(person1.age); //gives us 3.
```

How do I make a new instance without changing much code around? I have like 300 lines of code inside the object, functions(methods?) and everything. Wouldn't want to rewrite as a constructor.

Comment: ... 300 lines of code? Why not just do it right? You have almost nothing.

Comment: can we see a bit more of the real person object? The answer varies a lot between cloning a hash, a function, a model, etc.

Comment: Who downvoted the question? It has spawn a ton of answers, and each one has comments. This is the kind of questions we want to see more often.

Comment: @Dave, I know it's not much, and I don't know the proper way to do it in the first place. Well, now assuming that it's to create a constructor, since that's what I think you're suggesting. I'll do it the proper way if there's no quick and dirty path.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to clone an object if you want a new instance.**

One (shallow) way of cloning is to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. Note that this won't copy methods correctly:

```
var person1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person))
```

*More accurately,* you can iterate through your `person` object and apply the key-values to a new object instance (`{}`) if you want to copy methods (etc.). An "elegant" way to do this is demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/2456258):

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

---

That being said, there are tons of different ways to clone. Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) for comparisons.

Comment: @Downvoter? Care to explain why?

Comment: Does this work for functions and circular structures?

Comment: The stringify-parse strategy will ***not*** (it's shallow). The other methods in the SO post and the iteration method ***will***. See the updated answer. : )

Comment: I have like 300 lines of code inside the object, **functions(methods?)** and everything. You should have chosen a better option to demonstrate rather than relying on the link, or you should have flagged it as a duplicate?

Comment: *"Alternatively, you can iterate through your person object and apply the key-values to a new object instance ({}) if you want to copy methods (etc.)."* -- Does this not suffice as a "better option"? And I didn't see this as a duplicate. OP asked how to create a new instance of an object, ***not*** for the most efficient way to clone something. Those are completely different questions.

Comment: And yup -- "methods" are function members of an object. :)

Comment: Sorry, I got it now and your answer makes more sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use underscore, try this:

`person1 = _.clone(person);`

Answer (score 0):

Shallow copies, such as underscore's, or JSON parse+strinfigy won't copy functions (if you have any).

Depending on the structure of your current person object, it might be enough to do

```
person1= new person();
```

JS doesn't have a real "class" object type. Functions can be treated as classes in most cases.

Keep in mind that any person's properties that are, in turn, a reference to a global object, will be common among all instances of person. That's not necesarily a bad thing. I've seen class properties used as a datastore to make instances talk among themselves.

**EDIT**: I remembered about a post I read long ago about an ["elegant way to deep clone objects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object). It helped me a lot back then. It's meant to clone objects and properties of variable depth, but again, it won't copy methods.

Comment: Your code will result in [object Object] is not a function, it is object. exception

See the OP code person = {age : 2};

Comment: That's right, the current example given in the question is a shallow object and you can't instance it. That's why I said "depending on the structure of your current object". Models are objects too. Have an upvote for reminding me not to make assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

See Object.assign (ES6 feature) http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/object-assign.html

https://github.com/sindresorhus/object-assign